# PowerShell comparing numbers using -gt returning false results

Tags: powershell, powercli

I am querying some ESX Host statistics, and converting CPU time to CPU%, then using `Where-Object -gt` to only list those hosts where CPU is greater than 80.00 %. But my query is returning results where CPU is 9.00 because 9 is greater than 8, even though I have 80.00 in the query.

Here is my query:

```
Get-VMHost |
    Select Name, @{Name='CpuUsage';Expression={($_.CpuUsageMhz / $_.CpuTotalMhz).ToString('P')}},
        @{Name='MemoryUsage';Expression={($_.MemoryUsageGB / $_.MemoryTotalGB).ToString('P')}},
        @{N='NumVM';E={($_ | Get-VM).Count}} |
    Where-Object {$_.CpuUsage -gt 40}
```

And here is what is being returned. `CPUUsage` values are over 40 unless number begins with 5 or above. Like the last row which is only 8%, not 40%.

```
Name        CpuUsage MemoryUsage NumVM
----        -------- ----------- -----
server1.com 47.16 %  52.82 %        14
server2.com 50.07 %  45.75 %        13
server3.com 56.07 %  46.13 %        12
server4.com 48.56 %  48.24 %        13
server5.com 53.21 %  53.59 %        14
server6.com 66.01 %  44.20 %        11
server7.com 54.41 %  46.37 %        13
server8.com 8.08 %   9.18 %          2
```

Comment: But... you're not comparing numbers - you're comparing strings :) easiest fix is to swap the operands around: `{40 -le $_.CpuUsage}`

Comment: Won't work, b/c the string is formatted as percentage ("47.16 %"), so the comparison will throw an error. Don't format numbers as strings if you want to do numeric comparisons with them later. You can pipe the output of your `Where-Object` filter to `Format-Table` for display and do the formatting there.

Comment: thanks! but when i do that i get this error.  --> Cannot convert value "43.78 %" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: Would an integer have decimals, or a % symbol?

Comment: `[double]('47.16 %' -replace '%')`  Or filter it before the select.

Comment: Interesting that this is true, I thought it would make the right arg an int:  `4 -lt 4.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The percentages in your calculated properties are formatted strings. Comparing them to an integer will do a string comparison, not a numeric comparison, because PowerShell will (try to) adjust the type of the second operand to match the first operand.

Don't format values in calculated properties if you want to do further operations with the data. If you need formatted output you can pipe the output of the `Where-Object` filter to `Format-Table` and do the formatting there.

```
Get-VMHost |
    Select Name, @{n='CpuUsage';e={$_.CpuUsageMhz / $_.CpuTotalMhz}},
        @{n='MemoryUsage';e={$_.MemoryUsageGB / $_.MemoryTotalGB}},
        @{n='NumVM';e={($_ | Get-VM).Count}} |
    Where-Object {$_.CpuUsage -gt 0.4} |
    Format-Table Name, @{n='CpuUsage';e={$_.CpuUsage.ToString('P')}},
        @{n='MemoryUsage';e={($_.MemoryUsage.ToString('P')}}, NumVM
```

Comment: Thanks! but when i use your example i dont get any values for CPU. MEM

Comment: dont think this works because how can you have "where-Object {$_.CpuUsage -gt 40}" before you are converting in to a percentage?

Comment: @JohnnyCakes You're right. The reference value must be 0.4 instead of 40 there. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

actually.. i think this works.. i am comparing the decimal before converting to percentage..

```
Get-VMHost | Select Name, 
                    @{n='CpuUsage';e={$_.CpuUsageMhz / $_.CpuTotalMhz}}, 
                    @{n='MemoryUsage';e={$_.MemoryUsageGB / $_.MemoryTotalGB}}, 
                    @{n='NumVM';e={($_ | Get-VM).Count}} | 
             Where-Object {$_.CpuUsage -gt 0.600} | 
             Format-Table Name, @{n='CpuUsage';e={$_.CpuUsage.ToString('P')}}, 
                                @{n='MemoryUsage';e={($_.MemoryUsage.ToString('P'))}}, 
                                NumVM
```